# SFTP using VB.NET 1.1

Tags: vb.net, sftp, .net-1.1

one of the task assigned to me is convert the FTP Application to SFTP using VB.NET 1.1.

I am looking the on the internet but I am not getting  any free/open source API which support this. Is anybody know about this? if yes could you please share the code?

Thanks 
Jwalin

Answer (score 0):

You might check this link: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/70156.aspx

I don't know if they've updated for sFTP support, but it could get you started.